# Can admin monitor what websites has be accessed?

Tags: security, linux-networking, remote-desktop-gateway, network-security

I am using my company laptop, where is being monitored by company admin.
They have install Windows 7 OS on all laptops and some other security packages.

Currently I am usnig laptop outside my company network (Home Intenet connection). I have installed VM box and using Ubuntu inside it. IF I open some websites on ubuntu VM box. Would company admin able to monitor it?

Comment: It depends on the type of monitoring.  Ask them.  "If I am transfering money in my bank account, can you see that I am visiting my bank?  Can you see how much money I have transferred?"  The answer should be in writing or email.  Cc: your legal and privacy departments if unsure the answer will be truthful.  The traffic leaving your VM is still traversing your laptop.  If they use a always-on full tunnel vpn, then your "banking" traffic would even pass through your corp office or datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Everything, including this kind of monitoring, is possible for almighty sysadmins, but:

- It would be unethical.
- Work computers can be used both for personal and professionally confidential tasks. Monitoring such could be illegal.
- We have actual work to do. No time for spying employees.
- We don't have any interest in what kind of porn turns users on, as this probably is the main concern here. :)

Comment: Ah, no. "It MAY be unethical" - a lot depends on circumstances of the job.

Comment: Without the user knowing, it would be. Sometimes it's necessary to see what's happening on the screen. I prefer to use solutions that clearly shows the user when such happens and when it doesn't.

Comment: But ok, in _normal_ situations. Of course there's exceptions like if this is part of a crime investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For one, http://www.computerworld.com/article/2521075/windows-pcs/pennsylvania-schools-spying-on-students-using-laptop-webcams--claims-lawsuit.html -- except using remote desktop rather than a webcam. But plenty of other ways, too.